# How to submit a HTML form using httpurlconnection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, httpurlconnection

The website has the following form

Please login with your User Name and Password.

```
    <li><a tabIndex=2 target="_blank"
        href="/portal/site/login/en-gb/help.html"
        class="assistance redArrow">Need help with logging in?</a>
    </li>
    <li><label for="username">User Name</label> <input tabIndex=3
        class="authInput" type="text" id="username" name="username"
        autocomplete="off" class="authInput" /></li>
    <li><label for="password">Password</label> <input tabIndex=4
        type="password" id="password" name="password" autocomplete="off"
        class="authInput" /></li>

    <li class="persist"><label for="secureComputer"> <input type="checkbox"
            value="1" tabIndex="5" name="rememberMe" id="secureComputer"
             /><span style="padding-left:10px;">I am on a secure computer.</span>
            <br><span style="margin-left: 23px; font-size: 10px;">(Only check if this computer is secure and is only used by you.)</span>
    </label></li>
</ol>   


                <a tabIndex=6
        href="/IDM/pwdservice?a=fp"
        class="assistance redArrow">Forgotten your Password?</a><br>

            <input tabIndex=7 type="submit"
        value="Login"
        class="redBtn"/><br>
```

I am trying to login in a similar way to [this](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-automate-login-a-website-java-example/) .Here is how I am proceeding

```
URL server = new URL(url);
HttpsURLConnection urlConn = (HttpsURLConnection) server.openConnection();
urlConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
urlConn.setDoOutput(true);
urlConn.setDoInput(true);
urlConn.setUseCaches(false);
DataOutputStream printout = new DataOutputStream (urlConn.getOutputStream());
if (parameters != null)
      printout.writeBytes (parameters);
printout.flush();
printout.close();
```

where `parameters` is of the form `name1=value1&name2=value2.....&username=uname&password=pwd`

However the problem is that I want to add param name and its value for the **Login** (tabindex=7) ,as shown in the above mentioned link, input as well but I do not have a name only its value?

Is there another way to submit such form to login into a website? There is `loginSubmit` function on the HTML page, is there a way to use that for `urlConn`.